# When using Table inside a Flex with justifyContent, the table layout is wrong

Tags: html, reactjs, chakra-ui

I have a Table inside a Flex and Box. When I align and justify it to center, on the mobile version the layout of the table becomes strange, the first column is lost, and I cant find any solution to it. The only solution I have found is that when not wrapping the Table then it displays correctly, but that is not what I am looking for.

```
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" width={"100%"}>
      {/* Main content */}
      <Flex justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" width={"100%"}>
        {userLoggedIn ? <ReservedTable /> : <ReserveTable />}
      </Flex>
    </Box>

const days = ["Du", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Jo", "Vi", "Sa"];
const months = [
  "Ianuarie",
  "Februarie",
  "Martie",
  "Aprilie",
  "Mai",
  "Iunie",
  "Iulie",
  "August",
  "Septembrie",
  "Octombrie",
  "Noiembrie",
  "Decembrie",
];

const formatDate = (date: Date) => {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth();
  return `${months[month]} ${year}`;
};

const numberOfDaysInMonth = (date: Date) => {
  // Get the number of days in the current month
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  month += 1;

  const numberDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  let day = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-01").getDay();

  return { numberDays, day };
};

const checkDateComparison = (date: Date, selectedDay: number) => {
  const selectedMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const selectedYear = date.getFullYear();

  const currentDate = new Date();
  const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  const currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
  console.log("Current day" + currentDay);
  if (selectedYear < currentYear) return false;
  if (selectedMonth < currentMonth) return false;
  if (selectedMonth == currentMonth && selectedDay < currentDay) return false;
  return true;
};

export const DateTimePicker = () => {
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(new Date());
  const [currentDay, setCurrentDay] = useState(new Date().getDate());

  const switchDay = (index: number) => {
    if (index == -1) {
      return;
    }
    let olderData = checkDateComparison(currentMonth, index);
    if (!olderData) return;

    setCurrentDay(index);
  };

  const switchToPrevMonth = () => {
    setCurrentDay(100);
    setCurrentMonth(subMonths(currentMonth, 1));
  };

  const switchToNextMonth = () => {
    setCurrentDay(100);
    setCurrentMonth(addMonths(currentMonth, 1));
  };
  const { numberDays, day: startingDay } = numberOfDaysInMonth(currentMonth);

  const fullDaysArray = Array.from({ length: startingDay }, () => -1).concat(
    Array.from({ length: numberDays }, (_, index) => index + 1)
  );

  const rows = Array.from(
    { length: Math.ceil((numberDays + startingDay) / 7) },
    (_, rowIndex) => fullDaysArray.slice(rowIndex * 7, (rowIndex + 1) * 7)
  );

  return (
    <Table variant="simple" maxWidth={"40%"}>
      <Thead>
        <Tr>
          <Td colSpan={1}>
            {/* Button on the left */}
            <Center>
              <Button
                colorScheme="teal"
                size="sm"
                onClick={switchToPrevMonth}
                fontWeight={800}
              >
                {"<"}
              </Button>
            </Center>
          </Td>
          <Td colSpan={days.length - 2} textAlign="center">
            {/* Content in the middle */}
            <Text color="Black" fontWeight={700}>
              {formatDate(currentMonth)}
            </Text>{" "}
          </Td>
          <Td colSpan={1}>
            {/* Button on the left */}
            <Center>
              <Button
                colorScheme="teal"
                size="sm"
                onClick={switchToNextMonth}
                fontWeight={800}
              >
                {">"}
              </Button>
            </Center>
          </Td>
        </Tr>
        <Tr bg={"black"}>
          {days.map((day) => (
            <Th key={day} color="white">
              {day}
            </Th>
          ))}
        </Tr>
      </Thead>
      <Tbody>
        {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <Tr key={rowIndex}>
            {row.map((day, cellIndex) => (
              <Td
                color={
                  day == currentDay
                    ? "white"
                    : checkDateComparison(currentMonth, day)
                    ? "black"
                    : "gray"
                }
                bg={day == currentDay ? "black" : "white"}
                key={cellIndex}
                onClick={() => switchDay(day)}
              >
                {day === -1 ? "" : day}
              </Td>
            ))}
          </Tr>
        ))}
      </Tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```